# Getting errors when adding a foreign and reference key in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have two tables `Plane` and `PlaneType`.

```
 CREATE TABLE Plane 
(
    ID INT,
    Maker VARCHAR(30),
    Model VARCHAR(30),
    LastMaint VARCHAR(30),
    LastMaintA VARCHAR(3),

    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE PlaneType (
    Maker VARCHAR(30),
    Model VARCHAR(30),

    PRIMARY KEY (Maker, Model)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

After I insert these two tables I add the following foreign and primary keys:

```
ALTER TABLE Plane ADD FOREIGN KEY (Maker) REFERENCES PlaneType(Maker);
ALTER TABLE Plane ADD FOREIGN KEY (Model) REFERENCES PlaneType(Model);
```

The first `ALTER` works perfectly but the second gives me the error:

```
 ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table '----.frm' (errno: 150)
```

I cannot figure out why the first `ALTER` works perfectly and the second doesn't. Both are references to primary keys, and that's the only issue I could think off. I'm a mysql noob so it might be something very obvious.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: was about to answer before marked as dupe: having `maker` and `model` could be avoided if you make the PK of `PlaneType` an `AUTO_INCREMENT INT` column called, say, `plane_type_id`. Then `Plane` would have a single `plane_type_id` that could be used to `JOIN` on `PlaneType` to pull the maker and model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give that a try as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` and look for the `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` to get the specific error.

But I do believe it's a problem of indexes. Your primary key consists of Maker AND Model. Create an index on Model and the FK will be created.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answered my question perfectly.

Comment: @Kenshin This just answer the question and solves the error, though. Do notice that you might have problems later as a composite PK should have a composite FK (as in, the FK should have the same number of columns as the PK), read more in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323676/referencing-a-composite-primary-key.